# Xcode storyboard how to detect touch item

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, storyboard

I have a storyboard setup (the default) with the tabbed application template.

I want to add a BarItem and have that launch a URL when touched. I don't want it to go to a view in the app. How can I do this using the storyboard?

I am new the story board concept and not sure what to add to the story board to add a new bar item and then make it call a method.

Comment: I am confused, you want add a bar item on the bottom of the app? Like item 1 , item 2 , item 3  and you want one of those items to fire a method or you just want to add a regular button on the top bar like a navigation bar or tool bar ?

Comment: if you start a new project in xcode with the bar nav at the bottom. it defaults with view1 and view two..  I don't want view two to go to a view but rather call a method that launches a url..

Comment: I think what you want is not possible, try below answer but without a `viewcontroller` how will you implement it? I think your only option would be to create a new project without a tabbar controller and add a toolbar on the bottom of your rootcontroller and then add a button.

Comment: What is the delegate for the Tab Bar Controller? Are you saying that I cannot use a tab bar control with a bar item that launches a url? That seems unlikely..

Comment: maybe I understood your will wrong, you want a button on the tabbar controller that will lunch a url but not show  a view.AFAIK each item on tab bar controlller has to have a view controller. If thats possible I also wonder how.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to put a function in the ViewController code something like...

```
- (IBAction)barButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
}
```

Then go add the button to the view controller in the Storyboard and ctrl click drag from the button to the function.

This will make the button run that function when pressed.

Comment: This is with a storyboard. Just do the same.

Comment: so my first VC is the main VC in the story board.. do I add the button on that VC? I'll give it a try.

Comment: I have "Tab Bar Controller" as my first object in my storyboard. Do I put it there? if so, how do I connect the function to the bar item?

Comment: You need to put it in the VC that you have subclassed. So that you can give it some code too.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the Navigation bar

```
    //in viewDidLoad or wherever 
    UIBarButtonItem *openWebLink = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                   initWithTitle: @"OpenWebLink" 
                                   style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                   target: nil action: @selector(openLink)];

    [self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem: openWebLink];

-(void) openLink
{
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
}
```

If you don't, look at Fogmeister answer

Code not tested!